# Python - how to return list items from multiple lists of possible different lengths but get only non-matching pairs?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I have a multi line string as follows:

```
mystr = """
ACTIVE     3/1.1 
IDLE       3/1.1 
IDLE       3/1.2 
IDLE       3/1.2 
ACTIVE     3/1.3 
IDLE       3/1.3 
ACTIVE     3/1.4 
IDLE       3/1.4 
ACTIVE     3/1.5 
ACTIVE     3/1.6 
IDLE       3/1.6 
ACTIVE     3/1.7 
IDLE       3/1.7 
ACTIVE     3/1.8 
IDLE       3/1.8 
ACTIVE     3/1.9 
IDLE       3/1.9 
IDLE       3/1.10
"""
```

or with a list, it would be:

```
mylist = ['ACTIVE     3/1.1 ', 'IDLE       3/1.1 ', 'IDLE       3/1.2 ', 'IDLE       3/1.2 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.3 ', 'IDLE       3/1.3 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.4 ', 'IDLE       3/1.4 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.5 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.6 ', 'IDLE       3/1.6 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.7 ', 'IDLE       3/1.7 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.8 ', 'IDLE       3/1.8 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.9 ', 'IDLE       3/1.9 ', 'IDLE       3/1.10 ']
```

My goal is this...

for every pair of "x/y.z", such as 3/1.1 or 3/1.2, etc, there should be a matching ACTIVE and IDLE pairing.

In the event there is NO "ACTIVE" or NO "IDLE" pairing, then check if the pair shows both as IDLE. If yes, return it.
If there is no pair, then regardless if it shows as ACTIVE or IDLE, return the value as well.

I got this to work by doing the following:

this var is used to compare against some values of x/y.z, where "z" could be any value from 1 to 10. However, the pairing only matches on the "x/y." part:

```
lc = ['3/1.', '3/2.', '3/3.', '3/7.', '3/8.', '4/1.', '4/5.', '4/6.', '4/7.', '5/3.', '5/4.', '5/5.', '6/1.', '6/2.', '6/3.', '6/7.', '6/8.', '7/1.']
```

then rest of my script has:

```
outputsum = ""
pri_list = [] 
sec_list = []
stable_list = []

for intf in mylist:
  for g60 in lc:
    if g60 in intf:
      if "ACTIVE" in intf:
        pri_list.append(intf)
      if "IDLE" in intf.text:
        sec_list.append(intf)

for p in pri_list:
  t1 = p[p.find("ACTIVE")+11:]
  for s in sec_list:
    t2 = s[s.find("IDLE")+11:]
    if t1 == t2:
      print "Found matching pair!"
      if "ACTIVE" in p and "IDLE" in s:
        print "Putting valid ACTIVE/IDLE pairs into stable_list."
        stable_list.append(p)
        stable_list.append(s)

for pair in stable_list:
  for p1 in pri_list:
    if p1 == pair:
      pri_list.pop(pri_list.index(p1))
  for s1 in sec_list:
    if s1 == pair:
      sec_list.pop(sec_list.index(s1))

for i in pri_list:
  outputsum += i + "\n"

for i in sec_list:     
  outputsum += i + "\n"

print outputsum
ACTIVE     3/1.5
IDLE       3/1.2
IDLE       3/1.2
IDLE       3/1.10
```

The output from "print outputsum" is what I expect to get, but doing all the above seems long/complex.

Is there an easier/better/faster way of doing this?

I checked many different threads and examples, tried with sets, intersections and differences, and a mix with other loops, but I couldn't get the results I wanted. After a few days playing with this, I finally came up with the above working example. But I'm sure there's a better way than how I did it above.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use defaultdict, see below

```
# Clean up the data
j = [i.split('     ') for i in mylist]
j[:] = [[jj[0], jj[1].strip()] for jj in j]


# Make a list of idle/active for each key of "x/y.z"
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in j:
    d[i[1]].append(i[0])


# use some if/else to find pairing

for k,j in d.items():
    if j == ['IDLE']:
        print 'IDLE at {}'.format(k)
    elif j == ['ACTIVE']:
        print 'ACTIVE at {}'.format(k)
    elif (j == ['ACTIVE', 'IDLE']) or (j == ['IDLE', 'ACTIVE']):
        print 'ACTIVE and IDLE at {}'.format(k)
```

results in

```
IDLE at 3/1.10
ACTIVE and IDLE at 3/1.1
ACTIVE and IDLE at 3/1.3
ACTIVE and IDLE at 3/1.4
ACTIVE at 3/1.5
ACTIVE and IDLE at 3/1.6
ACTIVE and IDLE at 3/1.7
ACTIVE and IDLE at 3/1.8
ACTIVE and IDLE at 3/1.9
```

Comment: you can just use i.split() it will split by multiple whitespaces as one

Comment: @user1753919. thanks! dictionaries is one other areas I'm not too familiar with. I'll need to play more with dictionaries. I had not thought of using the "x/y.z" the key for each value pair, it makes sense. I think this method can work well with what I need since "mylist" may contain other text within each item, but it will always have an x/y.z value as well as either ACTIVE or IDLE or both. I can probably change the if/else to look for specific text within "j" and have it print "k" if it matches.

Comment: also, how do you read code that has something like "j[:] = [[jj[0], jj[1].strip()] for jj in j]". I've seen this type of writing in other threads and it gets confusing to me when it's in a single line. More commonly, when there is something like "(a for i in mylist if a == i)". Not sure if the example I provided is correct, but similar to it.

Comment: they are called list comprehensions, not going into lot of detail, they are equivalent to writing for loops (with ocassional if else) in one line. They make the code short and more readble for people who use them all the time, but it is hard to read for people who are not used to it. There are several tutorials on list comprehensions. Also check out dict comprehensions. Very handy! In my case, I am making a list of lists, to see the list of lists, use print j after each list comprhensions and u will see what I am doing.

Comment: thanks for info on list comprehensions. I'll search for those tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dastaframe groupby function.

```
import pandas as pd 
mylist = ['ACTIVE     3/1.1 ', 'IDLE       3/1.1 ', 'IDLE       3/1.2 ', 'IDLE       3/1.2 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.3 ', 'IDLE       3/1.3 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.4 ', 'IDLE       3/1.4 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.5 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.6 ', 'IDLE       3/1.6 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.7 ', 'IDLE       3/1.7 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.8 ', 'IDLE       3/1.8 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.9 ', 'IDLE       3/1.9 ', 'IDLE       3/1.10 ']
df= pd.DataFrame(mylist,columns =['one'])
df = pd.DataFrame(df.one.str.split(' ',1).tolist())
df.columns = [ 'act','num']
res = [ item for item in df.set_index('num').groupby( lambda x:x.strip()[:6]) if len(item[1]) >1 ]
```

Comment: thanks! I never used the pandas module. It seems simple what you did, so I need to learn more about pandas to better understand it. I tried your code and see that it adds a column of act and num, but seems to do it for every line. Is it possible to do it just once?

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned it up for you using tuples

```
mylist = ['ACTIVE     3/1.1 ', 'IDLE       3/1.1 ', 'IDLE       3/1.2 ', 'IDLE       3/1.2 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.3 ', 'IDLE       3/1.3 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.4 ', 'IDLE       3/1.4 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.5 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.6 ', 'IDLE       3/1.6 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.7 ', 'IDLE       3/1.7 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.8 ', 'IDLE       3/1.8 ', 'ACTIVE     3/1.9 ', 'IDLE       3/1.9 ', 'IDLE       3/1.10 ']

version_map = {}
for status,version in (a.split() for a in mylist):
  if (version in version_map):
    version_map[version] = version_map[version] + (status,);
  else:
    version_map[version] = (status,);

allowed_combos = [('ACTIVE',),('IDLE',),('IDLE','IDLE')];
for versions,statuses in version_map.iteritems():
    if (statuses in allowed_combos):
      print versions,statuses;
```

Comment: Thanks! this helps and is much shorter. I had thought about using tuples, but still didn't quite understand how to use them. I will need to practice more with tuples to get the hang of it. the only thing I'll need to do is convert the resulting tuple to a string.

Comment: if mylist had other text data within each x/y.z pair, such as "some data    ACTIVE    3/1.10" and using tuples with the allowed_combos, then in the "if (statuses in allowed_combos)" statement, does "statuses" have to have exact matches from the allowed_combos? I tried doing this as a test by appending a new list item with above sample, but I get error about "too many values to unpack" in the first for loop. So wondering if this example is more ideal for a list with two sets of strings separated by whitespace or if it can work even with other text data.

Comment: this code does not handle extraneous strings and cleanup, this should be done prior to this block of code if you wish to handle these cases